# Is there a cart or app that allows customers to personalize their products by uploading images/files to their order in django?

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

I'm building an e-commerce site for a client that sells personalized frames/canvas. The idea is that the customer needs to provide an image, choose from a variety of options (like size and layout) and a canvas will be printed with the customer's image with the chosen options.

I'm wondering if there is a django app or shopping cart with this functionality (i.e. that supports customer personalized products). I've browsed the [django packages site](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/ecommerce/), but didn't find any e-commerce solution with this functionality. Do you know of any out there?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks
Jimmy

Comment: Hi! I just posted a similar question and I was wondering that do you have any recommendations or examples? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005783/django-satchmo-developing-products-cart-line-items-with-personalized-fields-p)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a full-blown cart system called Satchmo (http://www.satchmoproject.com/). Other than that there are a handful of "starter" carts that you can use as a basis to roll-your-own (http://code.google.com/p/django-cart/), which is what I ended up doing.

Comment: Thanks @scoopseven. It seems like the right course. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing an app or a package. Thanks again for your time!