# (Django, Satchmo) Developing products/cart line items with personalized fields/properties

Tags: django, django-forms, product, cart, commerce

I'm looking into Python/Django to evaluate suitable e-commerce solution.
For now Satchmo package seems to deliver solution to satfy most of my needs with Subscription product type.

However, I still have home requirements to meet and I ended wondering that is Satchmo or some other cart/commerce package suitable for personalized products?

I need the user to fill in some "personal details" regarding Subscription since Subscription products/orders can be assigned to other users and/or to non-user.
Most natural way would be to enable users to add these details after product has been added to cart.

Line items should therefore have a user reference field or multiple fields in case of a non-user: email, phone,name,dob.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Satchmo, but [Django oscar](http://oscarcommerce.com/) is a very customizable e-commerce framework that could accomplish this. Also, Satchmo does not seem to be a very active project (their website is down right now, and the last github commit was 7 years ago).

In Django oscar you can create a customized checkout flow, where you could add your own step to enter those personal details.

You can read more about customizing views [here](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.1/howto/how_to_customise_a_view.html)

Another way you could do this, is customize the Product itself to have additional options before you add it to the cart. Therefore you specify the recipient of the Subscription before it is added to the cart.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I had totally different view about Satchmo and thought it was more active. However, I also ran into LFS "Lightning Fast Shop" which is also quite shutdown as a project but has the exact functionality that I'm after. Although it does require extending it with email and date fields but it shoudn't be that challeging development task. But in the end is it worth to bet on such an degrading project...

Comment: @user1271930 Great! Give LFS a shot then. Why do you say it looks shutdown? Although it is not as active of a project as oscar, it has had updates in the last 6 months. The two main reasons I see for choosing an active project are stability and support, both of which you should be able to get from LFS. I think that it is just a simpler framework in comparison to oscar, and therefore requires/required less development.

Comment: Well, here we are again with dependency/version related problems and it certainly doesn't help being a beginner with Python/Django. Every tutorial suggests totally different commands for setting up a workflow which makes it hard to grasp that what is the correct way, actually needed, complies to my versions etc. Django's own "App" tutorial is good but it isn't that general and perhaps has a bit too limited scope.

Comment: @user1271930 If you want help with a specific workflow from a tutorial, ask a new question and tag me in a link to it here